# Sqlalchemy query not commiting

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, formencode

I'm trying to create a simple unique username function for use in a Formencode schema. Here is the function:

```
class UniqueUsername(formencode.FancyValidator):   
    def _to_python(self, value, state):  
        user = DBSession.query(User.user_name).filter(User.username==value)  
        if user is not None:  
            raise formencode.Invalid(
            'That username already exists', value, state)  
        return value
```

The problem is that the query gets generated but never actually hits the database. The user variable simply contains the generated query, not the query results. How do I go about fixing this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
user = DBSession.query(User.user_name).filter(User.username==value).first()
```

also: is it User.user_name or User.username ?

Comment: thanks for the quick answer - could you point me to the place in the docs that explains this behavior? Thanks again.

Comment: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first